# Hamburger menu doesn't work correctly with my scroll effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a fixed hamburger menu with a scroll effect on my page. I succed to fix the hamburger icon.

The menu works on the top of the page, but when I scroll and click to make appear the menu, it appears on the top of the page off the screen.

Do you have a solution ?

You could see the website here :
http://veillaultadrien.github.io/index.html

And the code :
https://github.com/VeillaultAdrien/VeillaultAdrien.github.io

Comment: clean up your code errors https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fveillaultadrien.github.io%2Findex.html

Comment: It works. I feel stupid to not have think of VW3 to correct my mystakes.
Anyway, thank you ! :)